# Why SWFUpload does not start uploading?

Tags: c#, asp.net, flash, swfupload

I'm trying to work out why SWFUpload on a page does not start to upload file. After startUpload method is called, it invokes flash elements StartUpload and returns. I've set up all error handlers, but no one is called. It does not make query to the server. Why, and how to debug it? 
Thank you,

Comment: can you post some sample code so we know where to start?  Perhaps you are missing the upload progress event handler?

Comment: It even doesn't send request....

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement the upload_start_handler callback and set it to return true. That should start the upload.

*startUpload* calls the upload_start_handler javascript function which if it returns true, actually starts the upload.